# Custom navigation arrow in React-Native image slider box

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am using library

> react-native-image-slider-box

And I have tried to create a custom arrow < > to navigate the image slides instead of swipe left or right. I can get the current image index by calling 'currentImageEmitter' props and set it plus 1 or minus 1 but I cant find any provided props of library that can help me set the target value.

Lib : https://github.com/intellidev1991/react-native-image-slider-box

Answer (score 0):

You can try this package. It may help you with your goal

From https://npm.io/package/react-native-image-slider-show try

> npm install react-native-image-slider-show --save

Comment: Can I positioning those arrows as I want ?

Comment: I have used this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-looped-carousel  component and here u can customize the arrows easily . you can try this way  <Carousel
           arrows={true}
           leftArrowText={'＜'}
           leftArrowStyle={styles.carouselRightIcon}
           rightArrowText={'＞'}
           rightArrowStyle={styles.carouselLeftIcon}
          //  isLooped={true}
          //  delay={5000}
          >